# Is there a command to force Unity to reload menu data?

Tags: 12.04, unity, menu, hud

Not all the time but intermittently Unity will drop the menu from the HUD. Most often this is with GIMP but it has happened to other programs too. The menu choices are there but the content of the menu is empty and the HUD has no record of the commands. This can make even simple things like saving very difficult.

Is there some command that I am unaware of to make Unity go and reload the menu data from wherever it gets it and rebuilt it's menu information.

My Specs are:

Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit; Kernel Linux 3.2.0-40-generic; GNOME 3.4.2; RAM 16GB (Reported as 15.7GB); CHIP: AMD Phenom II X2 555 Processor.

Comment: This might be a bit over-kill, but would restarting Unity via the 'Run' Dialog `Alt`+`F2` and entering `unity` work?

Comment: Or..this: `sudo service gdm restart`. As GDM still controls the desktop somewhat (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried pressing ALT + F2 and type "unity", then press enter 
(this is the same as running "unity --replace" in shell).